# Showing a Sequence Converges to an Integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-integration, riemann-sum

**Problem:** Suppose $f\in R(x)$ on $[0,1]$. Define $$a_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{f(\frac{k}{n})}$$

For all $n$. Prove that $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges to $\int_0^1f\text{ } dt$.

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to formulate a partition and show that this function is bounded. Since the function $f\in R(x)$, it is automatically continuous, but I don't know if that's helpful. I'm not sure if I have to do an $\epsilon$, $\delta$ proof for this because I'm under the impression that those are essential for proofs if the function is bounded. We have no guarantee this function is bounded so I guess that would leave 2 cases. Perhaps it is supposed to be more simple?

Comment: Why is it automatically continuous? Riemann integrable does not imply continuous. On the other hand, if it is Riemann integrable then it must be bounded.

Comment: Maybe consider [Darboux integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux_integral)

Comment: What do you mean by $R(x)$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I believe it's the set of all Riemann Integrable Functions.

Comment: @copper.hat You are correct, if a function is continuous on a compact domain, then it is Riemann Integrable. So, being that this function is Riemann Integrable, it is bounded. Since it's bounded might I construct an arbitrary sequence of marked partitions converging to zero?

Comment: Your partitions are the sets
$$
\mathcal P_n = \bigcup_{k=0}^n \left\{\frac kn\right\}.
$$
Given $\varepsilon>0$, find an $N$ such that for $n\geqslant N$, the difference between the upper sum of $f$ over $\mathcal P_n$ and the lower sum of $f$ over $\mathcal P_n$ is less than $\varepsilon$.

Comment: This follows almost directly from the definition of the Riemann integral (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Riemann_integral).